# To submit a form in jquery by triggering one of sumbit button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

If a form has two submit button, Then i need to submit a form by jquery as triggering submit of one of the submit button.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit_button1']))
{
echo "form submitted by clicking submit button 1";
}
elseif(isset($_REQUEST['submit_button2']))
{
echo "form submitted by clicking submit button 2";
}

?>


<form name="check" action="">
<input type="text" name="text_val" id="text_val">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button1" value="submit button1">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button2" value="submit button2">
</form>
```

**question:** `$("form[name='check']").submit()` submit the form in script. I need to submit the form by indicating that form is submitted by submit button 1 or submitted button2 in jquery.

Please help me in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger click event

```
$('input[name="submit_button1"]').click();'
```

or

```
$('input[name="submit_button2"]').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
$("input[name='submit_button1']").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this.

```
$("input[name="submit_button1"]").click(function(){

sendData('button1')

})

$("input[name="submit_button2"]").click(function(){

sendData('button2')


})

function sendData(button){

//i assume your for data like this
    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone ;
//you can add your button as a parameter
  dataString += '&button='+ button

$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "yoururl",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
    //succed
  }  
});  

}
```

and at server side first you can check button parameter then apply your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call the "click" method on the button.

Try this...

```
$("form[name='check'] input[name='submit_button1']").click();
```

Comment: ha ha... In the time it took me to type out my answer, 3 others have typed the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("form[name='check'] input[name=submit_button1]").click(); //or
$("form[name='check'] input[name=submit_button1]").trigger('click');
```

Comment: both these answers had already been posted, so what is the need for duplicacy

Comment: @Matt. while posting an answer, you can see in real time if new answers have been posted. It could have been avoided

Comment: timing and connection issues might be the cause, "real time" isn't actually as "real-time" in ajax context, date/time should have been displayed by SO on the answers, so that we can determine the exact time span.